# Juno: cannot find `language-julia` package?

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I was following the installation instructions for Juno specified here: https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-julia-client/tree/master/manual

I ran the following commands:

```
Pkg.update()
Pkg.add("Atom")
using Atom
```

Then, when I open up Atom, I tried to look for the `language-julia` package, but Atom is unable to find anything called that. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be very clear: you installed Atom, opened up the Atom user interface, hit "Ctrl+Shift+p", clicked on "Install Packages", typed "julia" in the search bar, hit "enter" (you have to hit enter, the auto-complete results do not include "language-julia" on my system), and then "language-julia" did *not* appear? If that is correct, can I ask what did appear, and also what OS you're running?

Comment: @ColinTBowers My issue was that I was under "Packages" rather than "Install", which where I was taken when I brought up the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+p, entered "install packages").

Comment: I also cannot find any julia packages after successfully running those three commands pkg.....How to solve it?

Comment: @olivia did you check out the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comments, the search was being carried out in the **Packages** tab of the settings menu which will only show packages that are *currently installed*.  If you perform the same search from the **Install** tab the packages show up as expected.